# Sending values between AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, html

```
    <?php //Site root variable; ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/site_init.php"); ?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang = "en">
    <head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
    <title>Creativity Optimized.</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/imagesloaded@4.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "_scripts/main.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src = "_scripts/custom.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4.1/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/custom.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,400i,600,700&subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel='shortcut icon' href='_images/favicon.png'>
    </head>

    <body>



        <?php //Header include; ?>
        <?php require("../includes/header_include.php"); ?>


        <section class = "hero">

            <div class = "heroOverlay"></div>

            <ul class = "heroText">

            </ul>

            <ul class = "heroNav">

            </ul>

        </section>



        <section class="welcome-text-container">
            <h1>Welcome to MP</h1>
            <p class="welcome-text">
                MP Creations® is a unique advertising agency and visual design studio.
                We create visual content for almost any medium to tell compelling stories for our clients.
                Our methods rely on creative and strategic thinking. We do it with passion, love and care. See you soon.
            </p>
        </section>

        <div class="content-heading-container">

            <h1 class="content-heading">why us?</h1>

        </div>

        <section id = "mainContent">
                <a href="work.php" title="Forward thinking" class="item-buttons">
                    <img src="_assets/mp_forward_thinking.png" alt="forward thinking" />
                </a>
                <a href="work.php" title="Lets work together" class="item-buttons">
                    <img src="_assets/mp_work_together.png" alt="working together" />
                </a>
                <a href="work.php" title="Projects to play" class="item-buttons">
                    <img src="_assets/mp_play_projects.png" alt="play projects" />
                </a>
                <a href="work.php" title="Nesletter" class="item-buttons">
                    <img src="_assets/mp_newsletter.png" alt="working together" />
                </a>

        </section>


        <section id = "workPreview">
            <div class = "sectionGrids">
                <h2><span>Recent Developments</span></h2>
                <div class = "grid" >

                    <?php $all_portfolio_items = PortfolioItem::find_all();
                        foreach ($all_portfolio_items as $item) { ;?>
                            <div class="grid-item">
                                <a href=work.php data-jobID = '<?php echo $item->id; ?>'>
                                    <img class="grid-img-hover" src='<?php echo '_portfolio-items'.DS.$item->filename; ?>'/>
                                    <div class="title-wrap-hidden"><p class="job-name-hidden"><span><?php echo $item->job_id; ?></span></p></div>
                                    <div class="title-wrap"><p class="job-name"></p></div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <?php ; } ?>

                </div>

                <p><a href="work.php">See More Creations</a></p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <?php //Footer include; ?>
        <?php require("../includes/footer_include.php"); ?>

        <?php
            // chdir("_images");
            // $file = "somefile.txt";
            // $handle = fopen("$file","wt");
            // fwrite($handle,"peaches and cream");
            // fclose($handle);
        ?>


        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('mouseenter', '.grid-item', function(){

                var container = $(this);
                var jobId = container.children().find('.title-wrap-hidden').text();

                // AJAX request
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'db_lookup.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {jobId: jobId},
                    success: function(data) {
                        // success
                        container.find('.title-wrap').html('<p class="job-name">'+ data +'</p>');
                                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        // error
                        alert(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            });


                $(document).on('mouseleave', '.grid-item', function(){

              var container = $(this);
              container.find('.title-wrap').html('<p class="job-name"></p>');

        });
        });
        </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I have this php that loads in some images from a database to the front end. What I want to do now is when I hover over (mouseover) an image, I want to pass the $item->job_id to another php script using AJAX so that I can use that job_id to look up the name of that image from another table in the database.

the other php script might simply look something like this

```
    <?php require_once("../includes/site_init.php");
require_once("../includes/site_init.php");

if(isset($_POST['jobId']) && $_POST['jobId'] !==NULL && $_POST['jobId'] !==0){
  $job_id = $_POST['jobId'];

  $portfolio_item_name = Job::find_by_sql('SELECT name FROM '.'job'." WHERE id = '" . $job_id . "' LIMIT 1");
  echo $portfolio_item_name[0]->name;
}else {
  echo 'result failed';
}
?>
```

So job_id would come from the AJAX request calling this php file and the AJAX itself would get job_id from the previous php up above. What might the AJAX look like for something like this? and what changes would be needed for the php scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**jQuery**](https://jquery.com/) and [**AJAX**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to asynchronously send `$item->job_id` to  a **PHP** page. The solution would be,

- Place the below jQuery code just above the ending `</body>` tag, like this:

  ```
  <!--YOUR CODE-->                

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> 
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $(document).on('mouseover', '.grid-img-hover', function(){
              // job id
              var jobId = $(this).parent().find('.title-wrap').text();

              // AJAX request
              $.ajax({
                  url: 'yourpage.php',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: {jobId: jobId},
                  success: function(data) {
                      // success
                      alert(data);
                  },
                  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                      // error
                      alert(errorThrown);
                  }
              });
          });
      });
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

  **Note:** Don't forget to change **yourpage.php** in the `url` setting of AJAX request.
- And on **yourpage.php** page, process your AJAX request in the following way,

  ```
  require_once("../includes/site_init.php");

  if(isset($_POST['jobId'])){
      $job_id = $_POST['jobId'];

      $portfolio_item_name = Job::find_by_sql('SELECT name FROM '.static::$table_name." WHERE id = '" . $job_id . "' LIMIT 1");
      echo $portfolio_item_name->name;
  }
  ```

Comment: I keep getting an empty array for the query result, like the " var jobId = $(this).parent().find('.title-wrap').text();" isn't saving the value, I tried it using raw numbers for job_id and it works. Any ideas what the issue is?

Comment: @PatrickTraile Not sure why you're not able to get the `jobId` using *that*. Perhaps this will work for you, `var jobId = $(this).siblings('.title-wrap').text();`

Comment: Rajdeep Paul if I do "var jobId = $(this).parent().find('.title-wrap:eq(0)').text();" I get the correct element but of course that gives me the zeroth element no matter which item I mouseover. How can I fix this?

Comment: still doesn't work not sure why at all, If you think of anything else please let me know.

Comment: @PatrickTraile Just for debugging purpose, do `alert($(this).parent().find('.title-wrap').html());` and `alert($(this).siblings('.title-wrap').html());` and tell me what is it showing.

Comment: The first alert gives me the html with jobid equaling one no matter what element I hover over and the second alert(the one with sibling) is undefined. Also if I alert text instead of html for the first one it gives me all the id's in a line, again no matter which element I mouseover like so(123456789).

Comment: Also had to change the mouseover event  to look at .grid-item because  it does nothing on .grid-img-hover which seems strange also.

Comment: @PatrickTraile That's probably because your actual code block may be different from the one you gave in the question. It's working fine for me, as per the given code snippet.

Comment: I've updated the code to show all the code on that page. Everything should be the same.

Comment: @PatrickTraile If you're binding mouseover event on `.grid-item`, then use this to get jobId, `var jobId = $(this).children().find('.title-wrap').text();`. However, since you're binding it on `<div>` container, not image, it will slightly give you unusual results. Further, I tested your code with my code snippets, and it's working fine.

Comment: Ok it still doesn't work on the img tag but when I use children with .grid-item, the console is now logging correct results, but how do I now update the p tag of just that element I mouseover to change its innerHtml? If i pass it $('.job-name') in the success function it updates all the elements p tag when I mouseover one.

Comment: @PatrickTraile *hmm*, in that case you need to change your jQuery a little bit, [http://pastebin.com/N8gu4dcT](http://pastebin.com/N8gu4dcT)

Comment: it works! had to change mouseover event to mouseenter. I have one more big problem though, It only seems to work the first time I do the mouseenter, on my second mouseenter, its telling me the data doesn't exists anymore. Whats happening? I've edited the code to show the current file with AJAX as well as the current php script its calling.

Comment: @PatrickTraile It's a logical error. See your `mouseleave` event, you're doing `.html('<p class="job-name"></p>');`. So, the first time when you mouseenter the div element, it'll show your `data` there, but the moment your mouse leaves the div area, an event will get triggered and blank `<p class="job-name"></p>` with no text in it will be put inside *title-wrap* div. So the next time it won't work because there is no `jobId` there now.

Comment: yep silly mistake, thanks a ton, edited the code to show the current working file. Also, if I wanted to instead store the job_id in a custom html5 data-jobID attribute instead, how would I pass the value of that attribute to the AJAX data?

Comment: @PatrickTraile You can use jQuery's [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) or [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to extract custom html5 attribute value. There are plenty of [documents and Q/A](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20get%20html5%20data%20attribute&rct=j) regarding this. For example, in your case you can extract `jobId` like this: `var jobId = container.find('a[href="work.php"]').attr('data-jobID');`. Also, if your issue is resolved, please [mark the answer as *accepted*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 0):

I would write the jobid right into the image:

```
<img src="img.jpg" jobid="test">


<script href="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
imgs=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
 imgs.forEach(function(let img){
    img.onmouseover=function(){
    jobid=img.jobid;
    $.ajax({
       url:"yourtitle.php",
       method:"GET",
       data:{a:jobid},
       }).done(function(data){
       alert(data);
    });
    });
    };
    });
   };
   </script>
```

You have to download jquery on jquery.com

And your php

```
<?php
$jobid=$_GET["a"];
//do whatever
echo $status;
?>
```

Comment: what is img.href? also not familiar with "let" I'll look it up though and I would just change that onclick to onmouseover right? but seeing that the img tag doesnt have an href attribute where did that come from?

Comment: also, where is the job_id being passed to the AJAX? I'm new to AJAX so I might ask some silly questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
function createRequest() {
    try {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (tryMS) {
        try {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (otherMS) {
            try {
                request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (failed) {
                request = null;
            }
        }
    } 
    return request;
}

window.onload =initpage;

function initpage(){
    $(".job-name").mouseover= fooFunction;
}

function fooFunction(){
    request=createRequest();
    if(request ==null){
        alert("Error");
    }else{
        var jobID=$(this).text() ;
        var jobId= escape(jobID);
        var url = "yourPhpScript.php?n="+jobId;
        request.onreadystatechange =  function_you_want_to_run_on_success;
        request.open("GET",url,true);
        request.send("null");
    }
}
```

you can use this Php Script

```
$b=$_GET['n'];

$query="SELECT * FROM fooTable WHERE colum_name='$a'";
$result=mysqli_query($d_connection_objject,$query);
```

Hope this helps :)